# TSP - Held-Karp vs Dantzig et al

Tags: traveling-salesman

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the Held-Karp $O(n^2 2^n)$ solution and the cutting-plane method pioneered by Dantzig, Fulkerson and Johnson.

Held-Karp is $O(n^2 2^n)$ which result is computational times that are excessive. To quote Cook:

> This is disappointing since for $n = 30$ the Held-Karp guarantee
> is already quite a large number, and for $n = 100$ it is an impossibly
> large number to handle with today's computing platforms.
>
> http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/methods/progress/progress.htm

Yet we see, empirically, that solutions can be had in seconds for reasonable $n$'s.

I had initially thought that Dantzig et al. solutions were just "*good enough*" but Applegate et al write:

> The cutting-plane method is the core of nearly all successful
> approaches proposed to date for obtaining provably optimal solutions
> to the TSP, and it remains the only known technique for solving
> instances having more than several hundred cities
>
> [http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/papers/dfj_mathprog.pdf](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebico/papers/dfj_mathprog.pdf)

Why is one solution different from the other? Why is Held-Karp the best possible solution but Dantzig et al is also *"provably optimal"* and considerably faster? Given that Dantzig does not seem to have a subexponential time upper bound, why is it so much faster in practice?

In particular, I'm looking for an English explanation, not a math one. I'd like to explain this to my friends.

See Also:

[https://www.cs.uleth.ca/~benkoczi/OR/read/tsp-dantzig-fulkerson-johnson-54.pdf](https://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Ebenkoczi/OR/read/tsp-dantzig-fulkerson-johnson-54.pdf)

Comment: I'm surprised you can't find any differences between those two algorithms.  They are very different algorithms for the same problem. I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.   I'm not sure what you mean by "Why is one solution different from the other?"  What is the "one solution", "the other", and how exactly are you hoping someone will answer a "Why" question? Can you [edit] your question to make it more specific?  You might elaborate on your understanding and what specifically puzzles you.

Comment: On is O(n^2 2^n) which result is computational times that are excessive.To quote Cook "This is disappointing since for n=30 the Held-Karp guarantee is already quite a large number, and for n=100 it is an impossibly large number to handle with today's computing platforms." Yet we see, empirically, that solutions can be had in seconds for reasonable n's. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: That sounds like a different topic yet, one that has nothing to do with Dantzig et al and only has to do with Held-Karp... but I still don't understand what the exact question is.  Can  you [edit] the question to ask a specific, concrete question?

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I seem to recall that the cutting plane approach of Dantzig may not be known to have time bounds better than Held-Karp  -- i.e.: it is possible that you may need to eliminate a lot of subtours before getting your solution -- even though in practical scenarios, it seems to not hit these theoretical worst-case scenarios very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect.  Usually questions of the form "What is the difference between [these two algorithms]?" fare poorly.  How are we supposed to answer that?  I could say "Well, they're different".  I could say "Look, lines 1-27 are different".  Somehow I doubt those will be useful.  Are you asking about the difference between the algorithms?  between their running times?  between the solutions they output?  Are you asking whether one algorithm is provably faster?  I'm having a hard time telling what the question is.

Comment: I also see claims in there that seem like they lack support; e.g., who calls "Held-Karp the best possible solution"?  I suspect there may be an erroneous premise behind the question, but because the premises aren't clear to me, I'm not sure what exactly the misunderstanding might be.  Also, I recommend you distinguish between an algorithm and its running time: it's not correct that Held-Karp is $O(n^2 2^n)$, though might be the (worst-case) running time of Held-Karp.  Are you aware that an algorithm might run faster on many inputs than its worst-case running time?

Comment: "Solutions in seconds" for moderate $n$ come from Dantzig et al.'s cutting plane algorithm. This is one *algorithm*, Held-Karp is another *algorithm*. Both promise to return an optimal *solution*, so if there is a unique optimal solution they will both find the same solution (and if not, they will find equal-cost but possibly-different solutions). Held-Karp uses dynamic programming to do so and always takes $\Theta(n^22^n)$ time; Dantzig et al. uses cutting planes on top of the Simplex Method and comes with no subexponential time upper bounds that I know of but is fast in practice.

Comment: I find it curious that Dantzig doesn't have a sub exponential time yet it works in practice. I guess that's the crux of the question.

Comment: Average case complexity is different from worst case complexity. E.g. interpolation search has $\Theta(\log \log n)$ average case complexity and $\Theta(n)$ worst case complexity. Meanwhile binary search has $\Theta(\log n)$ complexity for both average cases and worst cases.

Comment: @rus9384 - If you expand on that some and make it an answer you'll get the bounty. That's the best explanation I've seen so far. Thanks!